# Trying to do a non correlated subquery and keep getting this error

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to write a sub query

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ProductID = (
    SELECT ProductID 
    FROM dbo.OrderDetails 
    WHERE Quantity >= 120
);
```

After executing I get this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm sure it's close and this is beginner material but I've spent way too long on this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `IN` keyword; e.g.,

```
SELECT ProductName
    FROM dbo.Products
    WHERE
        ProductID IN
            (
                SELECT ProductID
                    FROM dbo.OrderDetails
                    WHERE Quantity >= 120
            )
```

The `=` comparison operator does single value comparisons, while the `IN` comparison operator asks if the left value is in the set on the right.  Check out [MySQL 8.0 Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html).

Technically, a correlated sub-query references the outer table.  In this case, your sub-query is standalone and uncorrelated (e.g., `SELECT ProductID FROM dbo.OrderDetails WHERE Quantity >= 120` can be executed as a standalone query).  An example of a correlated sub-query might be:

```
SELECT ProductName
    FROM dbo.Products AS Outer
    WHERE
        ProductID IN
            (
                SELECT ProductID
                    FROM dbo.OrderDetails
                    WHERE
                        Quantity >= 120
                        AND Quantity <= Outer.Available
            );
```

On a loosely related note, consider using `JOIN`s in place of sub-queries whenever possible, as `JOIN`s are generally more efficient; e.g.,

```
SELECT ProductName
    FROM
        dbo.Products p
        JOIN dbo.OrderDetails od ON ( p.ProductID = od.ProductID )
    WHERE
        od.Quantity >= 120
```

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking this way too much I forgot those were even options.